# if i want to distribute P things to N things where the order matter, then it is a permutation, right?

Tags: combinatorics

if i want to find the total number of ways of distributing a number of P identical things to a number of distinguishable N things, where ($p_{1}, p_{2}$,...,$p_{N}$)≠
($p_{2}, p_{1}$,...,$p_{N}$), and $\sum p_{i}=P$, then it is a permutation since the order matter here, right?  and the following will be the formula for calculating the total number of ways
$$\frac{(P+N-1)!}{(P)!(N-1)!}$$
Is that right?

Comment: the answer there points to a link which i believe answered my question, thanks!